# CubeIDE, UART interrupt mode, Calculator Project

Tags: c, embedded, stm32f4discovery

```
#include "main.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

uint8_t gelendata[4];

void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart){

       HAL_UART_Receive_IT(huart, gelendata, 1);
}

#define TOPLAMA 1
#define CIKARMA 2

UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;

void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);

int main(void)
{
  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  
  uint8_t state = 0;
  uint8_t data[] = "lutfen islem seciniz.\n";
  uint8_t data1[] = "1.toplama\n";
  uint8_t data2[]=  "2.cikarma\n ";
  uint8_t islem = 0;
  uint16_t birincisayi = 0;
  uint16_t ikincisayi = 0;
  uint16_t sonuc[1];
  while (1)
  {
    if(state == 0)
    {
      HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, data, sizeof(data), 1000);
      HAL_Delay(300);
      HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, data1, sizeof(data1), 1000);
      HAL_Delay(300);
      HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, data2, sizeof(data2), 1000);
      HAL_Delay(300);
      state = 1;
    }

    if(state == 1 && gelendata[0] != 0)
    {
      if(gelendata[0] == 1)
      {
        *data = "toplama islemi icin birinci sayiyi giriniz.\n";
        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, data, sizeof(data), 1000);
        state = 2;
        gelendata[0] =0;
        islem = TOPLAMA;
      }
      if(gelendata[0] == 2)
      {
        *data = "cikarma islemi icin birinci sayiyi giriniz.\n";
        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, data, sizeof(data), 1000);
        state = 2;
        gelendata[0] =0;
        islem = CIKARMA;
      }
    }
    if(state == 2 &&  gelendata[0] != 0)
    {
      if(gelendata[0] == 2)
      {
        *data = "ikinci  sayiyi giriniz.\n";
        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, data, sizeof(data), 1000);
        state = 3;
        birincisayi = gelendata[0];
        gelendata[0] =0;
      }
    }
    if(state == 3 && gelendata[0] != 0)
    {
      ikincisayi = gelendata[0];
      if(islem == TOPLAMA)
      {
        sonuc[0] = birincisayi + ikincisayi;
        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, sonuc, sizeof(sonuc), 1000);
      }
      if(islem == CIKARMA)
      {
        sonuc[0] = birincisayi - ikincisayi;
        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, sonuc, sizeof(sonuc), 1000);          
      }
    } //end state == 3 && gelendata[0] != 0
  } //end while(1)
} //end main()
...
```

I am new at CubeIDE, as a project I am trying to do Calculator with UART Interrupt mode. But, the terminal does not receive any messages I just see:
lutfen islem seciniz.
1.toplama
2. cikarma
after entering 1 or 2 to the terminal after that messages I dont get any result.
What should I do?
I am using stm32f4-Discovery Board

Comment: You don't seem to kick off the receive anywhere. You only call `HAL_UART_Receive_IT()` in your callback, but that will never be called, since you never start receiving before that. You're also comparing the character to numeric `1` or `2`, rather than the ASCII characters `'1'` or `'2'`.

Comment: @pmacfarlane Sir, thank you for commenting. I am new to this thing and I dont really understand how this works. Can you explain more clearly to me. It would be helpful. Thank you so much for your patience.

Comment: Please format your code so that it becomes readable. Formatting includes empty lines where appropriate and no empty lines where inappropriate, consistent brace placement, consistent indention depth etc etc.

Comment: @Łemma 1 and '1' are not the same character. In binary representation, number 1 is 0b00000001, but character '1' comes from ASCII Table (look it up), where printable (and other) characters have numeric codes. Numbers in that table start at 0x30 (so character 0 is actually numerical value 0x30, 1 is 0x31, letters have their own values). As for you not starting `HAL_UART_Receive_IT()`, basically, you don't start reception the first time. You restart reception in callback, which will be called after you received something, but you don't start the first reception, it should be in `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear to me why you are using interrupts here. Your program seems to (attempt to) do one thing, and doesn't have any other processing that needs to be done. You might as well use the regular polling receive function rather than interrupts and callbacks. It's not really clear why you're using a state machine either.

You could make your life easier by making some helper functions for transmitting and receiving on the UART. Something like (completely untested code):

```c
void print_str(char *str)
{
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, str, strlen(str), 1000);
}

void receive_str(char *str, int len)
{
    int nrec = 0;

    while (nrec < len - 1)
    {
        if (HAL_UART_Receive(&huart2, &str[nrec], 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY) != HAL_OK)
        {
            // Handle error
        }
        if (str[nrec] == '\n')
            break;
        ++ nrec;
    }
    str[nrec] = '\0';
}
```

Then you could write simpler code for printing your menu and reading the user's response:

```c
char buff[100];

print_str("Please choose 1 or 2: ");
receive_str(buff, sizeof buff);

if (strcmp(buff, "1") == 0)
{
    print_str("You typed 1! Well done.\r\n");
}
...
```

You'd want to add proper error handling (as most HAL functions can return errors), but you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am doing intership right now and my mentor tell me to "calculator with uart interrupt mode" so, I am trying to that way. Thank you for solution and have a great day.